# Проблемка с ботом и банами

Tags: python, aiogram

Здравствуйте дорогие друзья по программированию. Я пишу своего бота для личного проекта на aiogram и у меня возникла проблема в команде бана по ID с последующим постом с причиной бана итд, а так же самим баном по всем чатам которые занесены в список. Появляется такая вот ошибка. Хотя при вводе команды /глобан ID причина;ссылка ничего не нарушалось

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-82' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=BadRequest('Participant_id_invalid')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "c:\Users\Пользователь\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Я ебал\main.py", line 85, in local_ban_user
    await bot.ban_chat_member(e, ban_id)
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 1838, in ban_chat_member
    return await self.request(api.Methods.BAN_CHAT_MEMBER, payload)
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 141, in detect
    raise cls(description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Participant_id_invalid
```

Вот мой код/функция/хэндл для бана коку как удобно

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['глобан'])
async def ban_user(message: types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id in ADMIN2 or message.from_user.id in ADMIN3:
        if message.text:
            x = message.get_args().split(' ', 1)
            y = x[1].split(';', 2)
        cur.execute(f"UPDATE users SET block = 1 WHERE user_id = {x[0]}")
        conn.commit()

        await bot.send_message(SLIV, f'<b>Пользователь забанен!\n<a href="tg://user?id={x[0]}">Открыть профиль</a>\nID:{x[0]}\nПричина: {y[0]}\n<a href="{y[1]}">Открыть доказательство</a></b>', parse_mode='html')

        for i in BAZABAN:
            await bot.ban_chat_member(i, x[0])
```

Comment: текст со скриншота читать никто не будет, причины обозначены в правилах сайта :) приведите всю текстовую информацию в виде текста.

Comment: Минуту сейчас прикреплю текст

Comment: Сразу отвечу ID человека был введён правильно

Comment: ```aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Participant_id_invalid``` вот ваша ошибка

Comment: именно так, теперь понятно почему ошибки надо не скринить а читать?)

Comment: Ну понятно что id введен не верно как говорит AIOGRAM, но ID как раз таки был введен верно

Comment: как определили что айди введен верно? посмотрели отладчиком, знаете какое значение передается но не сообщили в вопросе? пока данные для того чтоб вам помочь приходится тащить клещами :)

Comment: Уже пофиксил все. Там база данных не але